# Running input from stdin through pipeline

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

I have a pipeline of (two) commands that I need to process input from terminal.
With one command, this would be easy:

```
grep "b"
```

reads from stdin, which is terminal and prints lines containing b to stdout (also terminal).

But if I pipeline another command, for example:

```
grep "b" | tr 'a' 'a'
```

it still takes input from terminal, but does not ever output anything.
The only way I could force it to do anything is by starting the pipeline with file like so:

```
cat "file.txt" | grep "b" | tr 'c' 'a'
```

Then it behaves like expected, printing the lines of file.txt that contain b and replacing all occurences of c with a.

So, is there any way for this to read stdin instead of "file.txt", like it does when there is only one command?

```
cat - | grep "b" | tr 'c' 'a'
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways to do this.  A common way would be to use "read" to read input from a stdin. Unfortunately this only handles 1 line at a time so its normally encapsulated in a loop.

Another, more hackey solution might be to use a named pipe or socket to "inject" input from another TTY or socket.

For some kinds if guided input it might be appropriate to use "expect" in place of read.

Comment: Read in a loop worked for me. Hoped for an one-liner, though :(

Answer (score 1):

`grep b | tr c a` *does* read from the terminal. You don't immediately see the output from the entire pipeline because [there's a buffer between `grep` and `tr`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/108618).

Possible scenarios:

- If you write enough matching data then the buffer will eventually fill up, `tr` will get some input and you will see some output. This is hard to get with purely manual input because [the buffer can be relatively large](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/108618)
- If you indicate EOF by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then `tr` will get all it should get and you will see all the output you expect. It's easy to test this manually.
- *But* if you give up instead and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then you will terminate the pipeline and lose whatever data is in the buffer. I guess this is what you did, this is why you think the command "does not ever output anything".

Your `grep` may or may not support the `--line-buffered` option. If it does then the following command will print matching lines immediately:

```
grep --line-buffered b | tr c a
```

You may have experienced the problem with something other than `grep`. For any program try these general solutions (where `grep b` is only an example):

```
stdbuf -o L grep b | tr c a
unbuffer -p grep b | tr c a    # probably without echoing input
```

Note [`stdbuf` and `unbuffer` work in different ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97327/108618). I prefer `stdbuf`.